# SharePoint Online with OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

Does SharePoint Online stores documents in SQL Server by default?
If yes, can we store in OneDrive?

Comment: I don't understand your second question. Can you clarify what you mean "can we store in OneDrive"?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that SharePoint Online now stores documents in Azure blob storage to support the unlimited storage that is coming soon for OneDrive for Business. Either way, as service consumers we don't have access to, nor any visibility of, the back end systems.